# No identity field found for class of type: [ComponentClass] when creating persistent property for [RepositoryClass]

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j

**How do I get this to work?**

A lot of code examples say it'll be fixed if I just add @GraphId annotation, but that don't fix any thing and it is also deprecated.

I've tried removing member "id" completely, made visibility "package" and some other tweaks, but nothing seams to be the antidote I need.

I edited the code slightly so the line numbering does not match. the line marked with "**" in the component is the line "exploding" in my face. And thats the first access to the neo4j server.

I've installed a neo4j-server (community) locally and it is alive.

```
● neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-07-03 22:29:35 CEST; 23h ago
 Main PID: 30794 (java)
    Tasks: 52 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/neo4j.service
           └─30794 /usr/bin/java -cp /var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/etc/neo4j:/usr/share/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/* -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields -X

juli 04 20:47:28 serious01 neo4j[30794]:         at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:143)
juli 04 20:47:28 serious01 neo4j[30794]:         at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.executeBatch(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:170)
juli 04 20:47:28 serious01 neo4j[30794]:         at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.lambda$scheduleBatchOrHandleError$2(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:153)
juli 04 20:47:28 serious01 neo4j[30794]:         at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
juli 04 20:47:28 serious01 neo4j[30794]:         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
juli 04 20:47:28 serious01 neo4j[30794]:         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
juli 04 20:47:28 serious01 neo4j[30794]:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
juli 04 21:05:56 serious01 neo4j[30794]: 2018-07-04 19:05:56.044+0000 WARN  Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@1fc3783f[p=1,l=218,c=8192,r=217]={\x16<<<\x03\x03\x00\xD5\x01\x00\x00\xD1\x03\x03[=\x1a\x93\x89u\xBf...\x03\x03\x01\x
juli 04 21:08:32 serious01 neo4j[30794]: 2018-07-04 19:08:32.787+0000 WARN  Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@1fc3783f[p=1,l=218,c=8192,r=217]={\x16<<<\x03\x03\x00\xD5\x01\x00\x00\xD1\x03\x03[=\x1b0\xCd\xF0\x14...\x03\x03\x01\x
juli 04 21:10:44 serious01 neo4j[30794]: 2018-07-04 19:10:44.330+0000 WARN  Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@1fc3783f[p=1,l=218,c=8192,r=217]={\x16<<<\x03\x03\x00\xD5\x01\x00\x00\xD1\x03\x03[=\x1b\xB4-\xF96...\x03\x03\x01\x03\
```

My pom.xml (snippet):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Spring writes to the screen:

```
2018-07-04 21:10:42.686  WARN 11549 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jPersistentProperty  : No identity field found for class of type: org.tormodvaksvikhavaldsrud.app.initController when creating persistent property for : org.tormodvaksvikhavaldsrud.app.ActorRepository org.tormodvaksvikhavaldsrud.app.initController.actorRepository
```

My domain class:

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity
@Data
public class Actor {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue 
  private Long id;

  private String name;
}
```

My repositoryclass:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ActorRepository extends CrudRepository<Actor, Long> {
    Actor findByName(String name);
}
```

My component class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Component
public class initController implements ApplicationRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(initController.class);

    @Autowired
    ActorRepository actorRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        logger.info("Your application started with option names : {}", args.getOptionNames());

        **actorRepository.deleteAll();**
        Actor testActor = makeActor("TestUser");
        actorRepository.findAll().forEach((Actor a) -> a.toString());
    }

    private Actor makeActor(String name) {
        Actor actor = new Actor();
        actor.setName("TestUser");
        actorRepository.save(actor);
        System.out.println("Created:" + actor.toString());
        return actor;
    }
}
```

The stack trace dump from Spring:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:791) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:778) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.tormodvaksvikhavaldsrud.app.Application.main(Application.java:28) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction; nested exception is org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 485454502f312e3120343...
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doBegin(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:214) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.deleteAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.tormodvaksvikhavaldsrud.app.initController.run(initController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:788) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 485454502f312e3120343...
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1106) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1162) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0-0f49eb425368377c0c3905e0769af9b70c88d65f]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: Looks like, the root cause has to do with not getting SSL-compatible data when it was expected. How is your neo4j connection set up? Have you unintentionally enabled TLS/SSL in your application.properties may be?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you start your app and then call your code.

Change your class to something like

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyInit {

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(initController.class);

   @Autowired
   ActorRepository actorRepository;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyInit.class, args);
   }

   @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
   public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
      logger.info("Your application started with option names : {}", args.getOptionNames());

      **actorRepository.deleteAll();**
      Actor testActor = makeActor("TestUser");
      actorRepository.findAll().forEach((Actor a) -> a.toString());
   }

   private Actor makeActor(String name) {
      Actor actor = new Actor();
      actor.setName("TestUser");
      actorRepository.save(actor);
      System.out.println("Created:" + actor.toString());
      return actor;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but this results in exactly the same result as my code. :-(